# SARIM Model - Iterating through pdq, PDQ

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am trying to create a ARIMA model on R. I am trying to avoid the auto arima function and trying to loop my model fit result and use RMSE to optimize the parameters. Now, I understand that d and D can be figured out using ndiffs and nsdiffs function. However, I am confused in what are the range of p, q, P and Q that I can iterate through?

Thanks,
Pras

Comment: much of the times $p$, $q$, $P$ and $Q$ are not so big. So, you can just choose to iterate between $0$ to $5$. But, you should choose them based on ACF and PACF graphs.

Comment: Thanks Abdoul. I understand the importance of ACF and PACF graphs. But I am modelling it for 1000s time series. I am not sure if I could check each and every graph individually. Do you have any recommendation